# Configuration Management overkill for 3 node clusters?

Tags: puppet, configuration-management, chef, cfengine

I have 2-3 node clusters for our load balancers and various web applications.  I'm having to make the change in QA first, then in staging (on 2-3 servers), then in production (on 2-3) servers.  Is a configuration management tool like chef or puppet appropriate here?  Or is it overkill?  If it's overkill are there any tips to making this easier.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not overkill at all.  Start using puppet now, and it'll pay for itself in the long run.  Seriously.

I use puppet even if i'm only deploying one server, because I know at some point it'll probably have to be replaced, rebuilt, or another one added as a backup.

Comment: What Tom said, but with Chef :-) Being able to bring up a server from scratch quickly, even if its the only one you've got is invaluable.

Comment: Neh, Chef, Puppet, Capistrano, Cfengine.. There's loads of tools.  The important thing is using *something*.  I prefer puppet, because that's what I learnt on.  I'm sure Chef is good too, but I've not used it ;)